# I'm new to MySQL and is there any way a database could be compromised?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm wondering if there is any way that a MySQL database could be compromised? If so how might this happen? What further steps could I take to make my databases more secure?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer in any detail. The short answer - yes, it can be compromised. Mitigation: defense in depth and good backups.

Comment: Yes, a MySQL database could be compromised, in far too many ways to enumerate here. This question is too generic for us to answer meaningfully. The word "compromised" doesn't make sense without a lot of additional context.

Comment: ok, how might I be able to (in a nutshell) for instance, go to a site that is displaying some data from a MySQL database and get all of the table info/data from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compromised how? There's SQL injection to compromise queries performed on the database. There's account hacking, gaining otherwise forbidden access at the database level. There's bypassing the database completely and just copying the raw data files off the server.

"Secure" depends on your operational needs and how much time/money you're willing to put into it.

Comment: How could someone do that though?

Comment: They could guess your password. They could enter a quotation mark in a form field you're not properly sanitizing before saving to the database. They could hack your server. etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen in a myriad of ways:

1. The security of the server your database is running on is compromised. It only takes one unpatched vulnerability (theoretically) to give one unlimited access to your server (and hence your database).
2. The database itself (flaws in its implementation) is targeted.
3. Most likely: when you fail to sanitize user input properly, one can get hit by a SQL injection attack (sooner rather then later probably).
4. Social engineering / bad password practices.
5. The attacker gains physical access to the server.

... etc ...

Comment: How could I, or what should I know about "sanitize user input properly"?